# creating a new line within an excel cell with php

Tags: php

Is there any way to create with PHP when writing to CSV file a new line within the same cell. (Manually its ALT + ENTER)

Thank you.

Comment: Update the question to what you really want to ask.

Comment: @RichardBernards Ok done

Comment: This is not the complete question... I answered that question below... There was something else concerning databases, right?

Comment: @user2613707 : Have you got any solution? If yes, will you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the cell between double quotes and just put in a line ending.

When opening the csv, make sure Excel understands to use the double quotes as the enclosure of the cell

Comment: <lost /> You say you're inserting into a db here, but the question says you're writing to a csv file.... what are you actually doing?